# How to remove the following regex?

Tags: python, regex

I want to remove the following regex from the start of each line in case it exists `an:nn:nn` where n represents a number from 0 to 9 and a represents a number from 0 to 9 as well but could exist or not, for example we could have "0:00:30" i tried the following but it didn't work:

```
w = re.sub(r"[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}: ", "", w)
```

Comment: You have a `:` and a space at the end of you regex.

Comment: That's awkward, fixed thanks.

Comment: `r'\d?\d:\d\d:\d\d'` is a little more succinct.

Comment: @Tim Sure but, your regex could use some touch ups.

Comment: @COLSPEED yeah any comment that'd improve a method or suggest a better one is always embraced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend a slight simplification to your regex.

```
\d{1,2}(:\d{2}){2}
```

[**Regex101** demo](https://regex101.com/r/P9Vgxy/1).

---

**Details**

```
\d{1,2}    # 1 or 2 digits
(          # open group
:          # colon
\d{2}      # exactly 2 digits
){2}       # repeat group twice
```